# Fastest/Cleanest way to load a text file in memory

Tags: java, performance, text-files, coding-style

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I couldn't find one that answers my exact question.

I need a way to read a file as a `String` with the least code and as simple and as optimal as possible.

I'm not looking for:

```
final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

  // logic
}
```

And I know I can write my own helper class that does this.

I'm looking for something more along the lines of:

```
final String wholeFileAsStr = Something.load(file);
```

Where `Something.load()` is super optimized and buffers the file properly while reading it, taking file size into account for instance.

Can anyone recommend something from Guava or Apache maybe that I'm not aware of ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps [IOUtils.toString](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream%29) , from Commons IOUtils

Answer (score 2):

For a they detailed look at all various methods of reading a single file in a JVM try  the following article:

[Java tip: How to read files quickly](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly)