# Java Split XML file

Tags: java, xml

How can i split an long XML-file into pieces with each a predefined different name?

Example this is my XML file pasted in one long XML, generated for testing.
Now i have to split on envelope, each a new file.

```
<envelope>
 <tag1>1</tag1>
 <tag2>2</tag2>
 <tag3>3</tag3>
</envelope>
<envelope>
 <tag1>1</tag1>
 <tag2>2</tag2>
 <tag3>3</tag3>
</envelope>
<envelope>
 <tag1>1</tag1>
 <tag2>2</tag2>
 <tag3>3</tag3>
</envelope>
```

I have already work with splits before just not like this where there is no begin and end tag for the entire xml.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split 1GB Xml file using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169978/split-1gb-xml-file-using-java)

Comment: There are **tons** of duplicates of this question. Searching for 2 minutes would have found the answer.

Comment: Yeah but unlike them i don't have a begin and end tag for the XML.

Comment: @Eve: in that case your input is not XML: An XML document **must** have a **single** root element.

Comment: If everything else is well-formed XML, then using a filtering `InputStream` that adds a start- and end-tag could be a good solution.

Comment: A sensible thing would be to verify if the generation process itself can be made to write the output into separate files. That way you don't have to process the output file.

Comment: @Joachim its seems your comment beat me to the answer, if you like add an answer and I'll remove mine.

Comment: Don't use Dom, tru vtd-xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest making it well formed and then using one of the SAX or StAX solutions as suggested. The only difference is that I would avoid loading the whole thing into memory and instead inject the start and end elements by way of a SequenceInputStream.

for example:

```
InputStream in = new SequenceInputStream(
                        // start doc
                        new ByteArrayInputStream("<root>".getBytes()),
                        new SequenceInputStream(
                           new FileInputStream("envelopes.txt"),
                           // end doc
                           new ByteArrayInputStream("</root>".getBytes())));
```

Answer (score 2):

As Joachim said this is not an XML.

You can try to add a root element programmaticly, save the file as a temp somewhere and then refer to the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169978/split-1gb-xml-file-using-java) similar question on how to split it.

---

Answering the comment:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432852/fastest-cleanest-way-to-load-a-text-file-in-memory) might help you load it. I doubt you should worry about the size, since to split it you'd have to load it in memory anyway and then write it again.

Then something like:

```
final String xmlWithRootElement = "<root>" + IOUtils.toString(yourFile) + "</root>";
```

should do it. (without so many hardcoded strings)

One last thing.

I would suggest finding a solution that works. Then if you're unhappy with the performance you can look for ways to optimize it or you can ask a performance related question.

Comment: I would like to do that but the xml file is alot bigger it has 1000 "envelope" with also contains 50 lines. so adding it would be a bit too much

Comment: 1000 envelope elements is not a lot, is actually quite few IMO. If you had a 1000000 envelope elements than you might notice it. How big is the file ?

Answer (score 0):

How about just read the file character by character and identify `<envelope>` and `</envelope>` sequences. Whenever you encounter `<envelope>` you start capturing to a buffer until you reach `</envelope>`. This way the file can be as big as the filesystem allows. XML manipulation on large files is a headache :-)

Comment: What do you mean by 'is a headache' ?

Comment: @Simeon: XML parsing has a huge overhead, and in this example the input is not wellformed XML, so you need to work around it.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204827/xml-parsing-too-slow/6205624#6205624. I have parsed a 150mb XML wih SAX (unfortunately...) and it took no more then 5 seconds.

Comment: @ZeroPage indeed. Then what are we discussing ? :) OP said 'it has 1000 "envelope"'

Comment: I have no idea what you are discussing, the word 'headache'? :)